# Hibernate criteria get all rows where currentDate > startDate and < endDate

Tags: java, hibernate, date, criteria

I need get all rows where current date contains beetwen dateStart and dateAnd.

if current date - 17 JAN 2017 and

```
id  dateStart     dateEnd
0   01 JAN 2017   18 JAN 2017
1   01 JAN 2017   16 JAN 2017
2   18 JAN 2017   03 FEB 2017
4   17 JAN 2017   16 JAN 2017
```

I need get 2 rows with 0 and 4 ID in table

```
@Override
    public List<Raffle> findCurrentRaffle() {
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Raffle.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("dateStart",  new Date()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.le("dateEnd", new Date()));
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

return 0 rows

```
private Long id;
    @Column(name = "dateStart")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateStart;
    @Column(name = "dateEnd")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateEnd;
```

Comment: new Date() should not be called twice, they will have different values. Just a general remark, it won't answer the question.

Comment: Can you please show the Raffle class and tell what are the dateStart and dateEnd column types?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you conditions you have `dateStart >= currentDate and dateEnd <= currentDate`

To solve a problem, just change condition to `dateStart <= currentDate and dateEnd >= currentDate`

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.le("dateStart",  new Date()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("dateEnd", new Date()));
```